# Android Base Adapter

Tags: android, baseadapter

I am adding multiple UI elements like `SeekBar`,`ImageView`,`TextView` dynamically to the `ListView`.But Whenever I try to get the reference to these elements,I am always getting reference to the last element only.

e.g I have multiple `SeekBar`.When i press play button that `SeekBar` should update.But the problem is when i press any number of play button only `SeekBar` at last position is getting updated.

I tried

`seekbar.setTag(position);`

But of no use.

Comment: you should post your code

Comment: I am sure your problem with ViewHolder only. Please check your code.

Comment: Basically its a chat application using asmack like whatsapp in which we can send attachments of audio also.that sent and received audios are being played using mediaplayer with seekbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the solution is, I made my ViewHolder class's object local inside getView() method and assigned it to a global ViewHolder class's object on play button's OnClickListener.This change solved my problem like a miracle.

Answer (score 0):

The tag you are setting should be instance of your ViewHolder class.
Your code can be like this -

```
public class YourTeamAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static Context context;
    private ArrayList<TopDataModel> mList;


    public YourTeamAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<TopDataModel> list) {
        mList = list;
        context = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    // get item at givin position
    @Override
    public TopDataModel getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }

    // get itemID at givin position
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_team_status_list_item, null, true);
            holder = new Holder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tvName.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        holder.tvRank.setText(getItem(position).getRank());
        try {
            if (getItem(position).getImage() != null &&
                    !getItem(position).getImage().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(SharedHelper.decodeBase64(getItem(position).getImage()));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;

    }

    private static class Holder {
        TextView tvName;
        TextView tvRank;
        CircularImageView imageView;

        public Holder(View convertView) {
            this.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            this.tvRank = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
            this.imageView = (CircularImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @appkoder ..i tried your code..but then also my seekbar at last position is only getting updated.